# Switching Accountants - who does the audit review for past years?

Tags: income-tax, canada, accounting

If I switch my accountants, and the later CRA audits my returns (that were done with the previous accountant), who will be responsible for helping me with the audit: the new accountant or the previous one?

Wouldn't the previous one be bitter/unmotivated to help me much, considering I am not his client anymore?

What if the previous accountant is not even in business anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you paid for, but usually audit support is an unrelated engagement to the return preparation. If the accountant made a professional mistake, you can request correction and compensation from that accountant, other than that any accountant can help you with audit regardless of who prepared the return.

The original accountant would probably be better informed about why you reported each number on the return and how it was calculated, but if you kept all the docs, it can be recalculated again. That's what happens in the audit anyway.